# How much does the train between Hendaye and San Sebastian cost?

Tags: trains, public-transport, france, spain, basque-country

Does anybody know the price of the train between Hendaye and San Sebastian as of today? Just the price of a single ticket.

Each website appears to give a different price and I find the [pdf of the official site](http://www.euskotren.eus/sites/www2.euskotren.es/files/Euskotren_Tarifa_Orokorra_2018_04%20ok%20%28JUNIO%29.pdf) very confusing...

Is it 6.30€ (Interterritorial) or 5.50€ (PASSEUSK (LASARTE-BAIONA)) or 12€ (PASSBASK (LASARTE-BAIONA))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked them directly on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/euskotrenEJGV/status/1022028225902518273):

> 2,55€

Edit:
As mentioned by dunni, this price can be found in the Guipuzcua column (right) for 2 zones.

Comment: That would be in the GIPUZKOA section in IDA: JOANEKOA IDA (right column of the 3).

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but for a single ride I would say it's 1.95 €.

See the line

> JOANEKOA IDA

with 2 zones (Hendaye is in Zone 8 and San Sebastian in Zone 7 and you don't cross any other zones). PassBASK and PassEUSK are 24-hour tickets for different areas.

Comment: Thanks dunni. That could be as well, but the title of the table is "Bizcaia". I'm not sure if a train until Hendaye would be included as inside it.

Comment: It says Bizkaia, but also "1 · 2 · 3 · 4 · 5 · 6 · 7 · 8", so i would assume those fares include to the whole zone 8, not only half of it.